# Time-consuming queries to PostgreSQL Database are duplicated

Tags: postgresql

After restoring db-server from snapshot something strange started happening with our database. Basically it can be described as all time-consuming queries are seems to be duplicated. At least as pg_stat_activity shows it

[image: select from pg_stat_activity with only active queries shown]

These lines are almost equal except for their PIDs and client addresses.

Usually I'd think that that's just a mistake of dev team (multiple equal queries at a time in code, cron misconfiguration, etc), but one of those time-consuming selects comes from PowerBI which I believe to be quite reliable in terms of loading data.

Has anybody ever stumbled upon this problem?

Comment: `pg_stat_statements` does bot record a client IP address. The problem must be with your query (that you didn't disclose).

Comment: Postgres does not just run statements "out of the blue". If you see the same statement being run repeatably your application(s) are doing that. You need to look _there_. Maybe the end-users simply hit "refresh" in PowerBI all the time and thus the query is run over and over again. It's certainly not caused by Postgres itself.

Comment: Turned out to be neither of those. That's the way pg_stat_activity shows parallel workers processing single query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out that's the way `pg_stat_activity` shows parallel workers processing single query. You can make sure that's the case by getting `backend_type` of these records.

Comment: Confused the heck out of me, thanks!